# window.crypto.subtle not working in IIS hosted web application

Tags: javascript, iis, window-object, window.crypto

I'm using window.crypto.subtle.importKey() for one of the authentication process in my app. Its working when i ran it on node server but its not working when i hosted it on IIS.

> Error:
>
> importKey of undefined (Till window.crypto i'm getting)

Comment: What browser are you trying to use this in?

Comment: im trying in Chrome (its working when i hosted it in local server or Node js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer for this problem.
Chrome restricts the usage of WebCryptographyApi to secure origins. It means 'https'. localhost is a special address enabled for development. Therefore, to use WebCrypto in a real environment you need to setup a SSL/TLS server